# How to skip splash screen Activity on low memory Android devices?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-manifest, splash-screen

In an app with **minSdkLevel=9** a splash screen is displayed by the following code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int DELAY = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // ignore
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                    SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, DELAY);

        Utils.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // protect from exiting the application when splash screen is shown
    }
}
```

The activity_splash.xml layout file consists mainly of an ImageView:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/copyright" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Unfortunately, on **Nexus 1** the app crashes with *out of memory* error:

[image: Nexus 1]

There are 2 variants of splash.png - for mdpi (280 KByte) and xxhdpi:

[image: Android Studio]

Surely the splash image could be scaled down more and more variants of it could be provided (ldpi, xhdpi, ...) - but why does not the `try/catch` in above Java code help here?

And is there maybe a better way to handle this - maybe some directive for `AndroidManifest.xml` to skip `SplashActivity` and load `MainActivity` on low-memory devices?

Here the full crash trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{XXX/XXX.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
        at XXX.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
            at XXX.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
            at XXX.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Because it's not a OOM at that catch point it's a `InflateException`

Comment: We can do without the screen shots. You have the code, stack trace and one `catch` - it's **very** clear already.

Comment: Have you read [`onLowMemory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory%28%29)?

Comment: Really? At the trace bottom I see `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: .... at SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:16)`. And I didn't know about `onLowMemory()` callback, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relavant bit of the stack that tells me it's an `InflateException`:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    at XXX.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:16)
```

^ your method is here

The other "`Caused by:`s" below are the inner exceptions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{XXX/XXX.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Comment: Changed to `catch (Exception e)` and it has worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-size the Image from `.png` to `.jpg` format. This will decrease the size at nearly half scale. Then use a `largeHeap` tag in your Activities manifest file,

```
<application
....
   android:largeHeap="true">
```

Also remember to make a try catch block so that you can bypass showing the Splash screen and redirect to the main activity.

```
While( ! success ) {
   try {
       // load resources
  }  catch (OutOfMemoryError E) { 
       // do something to use less memory and try again
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). I have tried the loop, but it didn't really work (VM crashes): `boolean success = false; while (! success) { try { setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); success = true; } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {  }  }`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you even show this Splash screen? It's not good practice, it's code doesn't do anything other than just waiting for 3 seconds to pass, it's clearly causing problems yet you insist on fixing it rather than getting rid of it altogether. *Silly!*

Second of all, devices like N1 that came many years ago do not have the RAM capabilities like modern devices do. With just one bitmap you're exhausting it's resources. Either optimize your bitmap usage or get rid of it altogether and find an alternative if you have to have a Splash screen.

Comment: I show the splash screen, because it is a (word) game... And I have spent a lot of effort already to keep it running at minSdkLevel=9 (the lowest possible with GCM).